# "the word on the question" or "the word of the question"?

Tags: prepositions

For, example, let's consider I am a questioner at a certain blog.

I am wondering which preposition I should use when I ask a kind of question below.

I would like to make a questions (to potential readers), like, "Choose the inappropriate synonym or antonym that does NOT match with the word **on** the question or **of the question**" (The word **on** the question or **of** the question is described before the sentence above.)

I am personally guessing **of** would be correct. Am I right about this?

And then also, is there any case in which we could use the preposition **on**? If there were, kindly advise me.

Comment: I can't tell what "the word on/of the question" is. Do you mean one of the words *in* the question (any single word contained in the question)? Then it would be "*a* word".

Comment: Thank you for your swift comment. I mean, I am asking a question ( so that the readers need to choose the inappropriate answer. ), What I mean, is, when I ask such a question, will you confirm if I should use the preposition "of" ( which is, the question from me )? For example ( continued )

Comment: I am asking a question such as this, **Now, choose the inappropriate antonym or synonym that does NOT match the words of the questions. 

１.Antonym 

      Question Word : extraordinary A.

Comment: I am having a mile uneasiness if the preposition "of" is correct in such a case above...Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Give us an example question that you want to write. Then I think we can help you. We don't know what your questions look like, so we don't know how to help you.

Comment: @KentaroTomono The answer is **in.** **In,**  **In,**  **In.** See the answer below. Your sentence, properly composed, is: _Choose the inappropriate synonym or antonym that does NOT match with the word **in** the question._ (This is true in the sense you intended; however, your sentence is so phrased that a correct answer requires not only inappropriateness but also that it match the word, and thus a correct answer cannot exist.)

Comment: Maybe. Unless the intent is to ask for an answer that relates to the meaning of a given word or to an expression as a whole.

Comment: And in any event, what does it mean for an antonym to not *match* something? We can infer the intended meaning, but perhaps the ability to unravel that is not what the OP wants to test. Here, even lax me thinks this is off-topic as unclear as is.

Comment: @JimReynolds You could make a case for _any_ preposition here. "Under the question" is not out of the question, depending on context; but the answer here is **in.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is a question is given ahead of time the appropriate preposition is

> in
>   Choose the inappropriate synonym or antonym that does NOT match with the word **in** the question.

For example

> Q1. **happy**  1) laughing  2) crying 3) smiling  4) glad

"happy" (the word in the question) is neither "on" nor "of" the question, but "in" Q1.

You can have a

> question **on** *something*
>   question **of** *something*

but not

> *something* **on** a question
>   something **of** a question