# Appropriate for vs appropriate as

Tags: prepositions

This is actually the continuation of [my prior question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/101175/on-the-question-or-of-the-question).

Again, I am now trying to make a question in which readers need to choose **appropriate** words **that are not appropriate as/for antonyms** in the question.

For example, the whole current sentence as of now is below.

> Now, choose the word(s) that is ( are ) NOT
> appropriate for antonym(s) of the words in
> the questions. The answer is not limited to one
> choice.

> extraordinary

> A. common

> B. exceptional

> C. conventional

> D. average

In this case, the answer is B. Anyhow, I begin to have a question if the sentence of the very question is correct, where I am wondering which preposition I should use, namely, as or for, following after the word antonym.

Comment: No need for _sumimasen_ here! :)

Comment: We answer for free because we enjoy doing so! **antonym for** is the correct choice between _for_ and _as._ (You could also use **antonym of** or even **antonym to**.) Also: you don't need the word _appropriate_ here. It only confuses matters. Just say: **Choose the word that is not an antonym of the word in the question.**

Comment: I think OP was asking **for an antonym** or **as an antonym**. "Choose which words are not appropriate **as** antonyms **for** extraordinary".

Comment: @Peter The OP asks  **...which preposition I should use, namely, as or for, following _after_ the word antonym.** Or am I misreading that somehow? It seems quite clear to me...

Comment: *sigh* Two questions here! For the question in the title: **Appropriate as.** For the question in the body: **antonym of.**

Comment: I would get ride of the "( are )". Usually, if you do something like word(s) you just assume the singular everywhere else because it just gets too clunky to change everything else.

Comment: In this context, use *(not) appropriate as*, i.e. words that don't work as substitutes for the antonym. *(Not) appropriate for* is also valid, but it is a request for words *associated* with the antonym. We can use a 2-step process. First, find an antonym (say, extraordinary vs *ordinary*). Then find words inappropriate for that antonym, i.e. words inappropriate for *ordinary*. This is highly subjective since what makes something *appropriate* (and by extension *in*appropriate) depends on the context, and none is given in the quoted question.

Comment: Oh is this mine? Lol, I don't understand what I was asking about :).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my intrusion but I think neither of the prepositions will work.

My advice is to rephrase it to:

- Now, choose the word(s) that is NOT the antonym of the other words listed below. The answer is not limited to one choice.

or:

- From the set of words listen below, choose a word(s), which you consider NOT to be antonyms of the other words. The answer is not limited to one choice.

> Sometimes it is better to rephrase your sentence if you are having
>   trouble phrasing it the way you want it to be.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is not elegant English. However, "appropriate" can take a number of prepositions.

"X is appropriate as an example of Y" will sound normal to a native speaker.

"X is appropriate for that kind of use" will sound normal to a native speaker.

"X is appropriate to use under those circumstances" will sound normal to a native speaker.

I shall not try to formulate a general rule for which preposition will sound most appropriate to a native speaker under what circumstances. If any such rule exists, it may vary regionally or even from speaker to speaker. I would not worry about it if I were you.

In the specific question at issue, either "for" or "as" is grammatical. In the case of "for,", the question will be read as a contraction of

"Choose the word or words that are not appropriate for [use as] an antonym."

In the case of "as," the question will be read as a contraction of

"Choose the word or words that are not appropriate as [examples of] an antonym."

In any case, the question is wordy and thus in bad style. The whole issue can be avoided with

"Choose the word or words that are not antonyms."

(I do not even want to get into the sloppiness of word(s) is(are).)